# Getting same wrong result from query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have one problem, when i do my query I always get same result (2), it doesn't get right ID value:

```
    $query = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string("SELECT id FROM image WHERE file_name = ?");

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $this->name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)
    {
        var_dump($stmt->id);
        var_dump($id);
    }
```

Result is always:

```
$int(2)
NULL
```

And I dont even have that ID value in that table.
Notice: This query works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You're var_dumping `$stmt->id`, but you bound `$id`...!

Comment: i just want to write result, it is same $id have same value

Comment: `$id` is not the same as `$stmt->id`! `var_dump($id)` is what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [RTM how to use mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM image WHERE file_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $this->name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->fetch();

var_dump($id);
```

- you don't escape the whole query
- you don't need `store_result`
- you need `fetch`
- you need to `var_dump` the variable you have bound, not some other variable like `$stmt->id`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the escaping function, *especially* on the whole query string. That's a low-level function for exceptional circumstances.

Putting the query directly into the `prepare` call should fix it.

Comment: The escaping should actually do nothing in this case; if it did, it'd likely result in a syntax error. So, while you're right that he's doing it wrong, it's not the cause of the "error".